# How to optimize the repeated code in loop

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need a help on code optimisation.

I have below piece of code:

```
String asset_code = "";
for (int i = 0; i < asset.getIds().size(); i++) {
    if (asset.getIds().get(i).getName().contains("TEST")) {
        asset_code = asset.getIds().get(i).getAssetCode();
    }
}
```

There I am calling `asset.getIds()` again and again. Is there any way to optimise the above code?

Comment: If the getter just returns a field, there may not actually be a way to make this faster -- the JIT probably optimizes that for you.  But you can probably make it shorter.

Answer (score 3):

Use a variable to store the result of `asset.getIds`.

```
List<SomeType> ids = asset.getIds();
for(int i=0;i<ids.size();i++)
{
  if(ids.get(i).getName().contains("TEST"))
  {
   asset_code=ids.get(i).getAssetCode();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***UPDATED** to match the question code edits of Aug 10 at 14:43.*

Use an enhanced `for` loop:

```java
String asset_code = "";
for (AssetId assetId : asset.getIds()) {
    if (assetId.getName().contains("TEST")) {
        asset_code = assetId.getAssetCode();
        break; // Stop searching, i.e. keep first match
    }
}
```

In Java 8+, you can use streaming:

```java
String asset_code = asset.getIds().stream()
        .filter(id -> id.getName().contains("TEST"))
        .findFirst()
        .map(AssetId::getAssetCode)
        .orElse("");
```

Comment: Your solution works differently than OPs version. OP will return the asset code of the last match, your code the asset code of the first match.

Comment: @Tom I know, that's why I added the comment to explicitly say that. --- OP asked for "code optimization", and short-circuiting the loop is such an optimization. Only OP can decide whether the first vs. last change is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming UserProfiles is a list:

```
Optional<UserProfile> optional = profiles.stream()
            .filter(a -> a.getTags().contains("TEST"))
            .findFirst();
if (optional.isPresent()) {
    assetCode = optional.get().getAssetCode();
}
```

Comment: Strongly avoid `optional.get()` in favor of `ifPresent` or `orElse`.